# Pass URL to front end from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, variables, url

I am building a chatbot with pre-determined answers for the user. Some of the answers need text which will be clickable URL / redirect. Using this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL as a ref.

How can I pass an URL from my node server through to my front end application in a shortened fashion? E.g. "click *here*"

```
let url_one = new URL('https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Cotton_Candy/4smcwgEACAAJ?hl=en', 'Cotton Candy — Victoria Blakemore (2019)');

const Messages = [
    {
        message: `I couldn’t find what you’re looking for. Maybe try again but use vaguer search terms. This is also interesting by the way: ${url_one}`
    },

]

module.exports = Messages;
```

Comment: I'm not getting your question. You want to have answers that come from the backend?

Comment: It depends entirely on what format the front end application expects to receive the data in. If you are writing the front end then it can be whatever data format you want to design or reuse. Otherwise you'll need to read the documentation and/or collaborate with the front end author.

Comment: Are you just asking how to make an HTML link?

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL). The the first argument is the path of the `url`, followed by the `base`. The text for the anchor tag (`<a>`) is not part of the actual `URL` object. You will need your own object or data structure to hold this additional information.

See the example below:

```js
const anchorTag = ({ text, href }) => `<a href="${href}">${text}</a>`;

const link = {
  text: 'Cotton Candy — Victoria Blakemore (2019)',
  href: new URL('books/edition/Cotton_Candy/4smcwgEACAAJ?hl=en', 'https://www.google.co.uk')
};

const Messages = [{
  message: `I couldn’t find what you’re looking for. Maybe try again but use vaguer search terms. This is also interesting by the way: ${anchorTag(link)}`
}];

//module.exports = Messages;

document.body.innerHTML = Messages[0].message; // Processed as raw HTML on the client
```

You could alternately just pass the `url` without the base:

```js
const link = {
  text: 'Cotton Candy — Victoria Blakemore (2019)',
  href: new URL('https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Cotton_Candy/4smcwgEACAAJ?hl=en')
};
```

Here is how you render raw HTML in the React client using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```js
// Server
const
  anchorTag = ({ text, href }) => `<a href="${href}">${text}</a>`,
  link = {
    text: 'Cotton Candy — Victoria Blakemore (2019)',
    href: new URL('books/edition/Cotton_Candy/4smcwgEACAAJ?hl=en', 'https://www.google.co.uk')
  },
  Messages = [{
    message: `I couldn’t find what you’re looking for. Maybe try again but use vaguer search terms. This is also interesting by the way: ${anchorTag(link)}`
  }];

// Client
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: Messages[0].message
      }}>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I pass the link through to React front end it shows up as plain text and does not format to HTML

Comment: @ib95 I added a React example at the end.

Comment: This answer shows how trying to shoehorn a basic templater in to the server side can lead to other problems.  It uses string concatenation to generate HTML, so there will be no proper escaping, plus it uses dangerouslySetInnerHTML client side.  It will break in some situations and not work with some URLs.  A better solution would be for the server side to send only the required data and not have to worry about anything to do with HTML.  Then the client side should take that data and use proper react syntax to render the anchor tags.  React/JSX is your templating engine.